# Windows 10 update takes up all disk space with unknown files files

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, windows-10-upgrade

I have just upgraded my windows 10 installation with the new features update. On return, my hard disk was full and i have identified that it was caused by files with no extension. Around maybe 300 in  total, each file is around 200mb in size. Because of this, my hard drive is full. Here is an image:

[image: disk screenshot]

Great if anyone knows anything about this and what to do.

Answer (score 1):

#### It was caused by temp files on the hard drive

Run Disk Cleanup to delete temp files:

> To delete temporary files:
>
> 1. Search for Disk cleanup from the taskbar and select it from the list of results.
> 2. Under Files to delete, select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> 3. Select OK.
>
> If you need to free up more space, you can also delete system files:
>
> 1. In Disk cleanup, select Clean up system files.
> 2. Select the file types to get rid of. To get a description of the file type, select it.
> 3. Select OK.

Source [Disk cleanup in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026616/windows-disk-cleanup-in-windows-10)

Comment: Trying this now. Forgot you could do this too. Seems to be random system files (250-300 of them!), each 200mb, not temporary files. Will post results later. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tried it... it's still there. This solution does not work for me. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Hello everyone. I was using an old HDD and a copy of windows that had been modified by ASUS. Since I have transferred my documents, photos, etc... to a new, faster HDD with a fresh copy of windows from Microsoft. Sorry for not letting you all know when I did this